# Set Coldfusion ORM not to affect parent folders

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I came from PHP/MySQL background, and now I landed new back-end position as Coldfusion 9 developer. Im totally new with Coldfusion, so for learning and testing purposes I have installed CF on my localhost. On my localhost I have set and tested ORM, which worked perfectly, and it did not interfere with other parent folders. Once I uploaded my Application.cfc file to our main server, under site/project89/cfc/orm/

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cfset this.name = "whatevername">
  <cfset this.ormenabled = "true">
  <cfset this.datasource = "name_db">
</cfcomponent>
```

It affected the whole parent server folders, including main "site" folder where we have all other coldfusion projects that were build before.
Is there a way to set ORM to affect only its own subdirectories and DO NOT make any changes to its parent folders?
Example, enable ORM for site/project89, and prevent ORM on other site/project**.
Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated, because where I work no one familiar with ORM and I can not afford to crash our server again.
Thank you.

Comment: So is the new `Application.cfc` being called for the other (parent) files? You can turn on request debugging in coldfusion admin and check which files are being loaded if your not sure

Comment: I need ORM be enabled only in folder "site/project89" and its own subfolder files  site/project89/folder1 | site/project89/folder2 etc.. Sorry if Im being not clear.

Comment: is the `application.cfc` sitting in the `site/project89` folder? Edit: just read the question again - You need to move it there.

Comment: yes, `Application.cfc` seats in the `site/project89` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue you are having relates to the location/struture of your application.

You need to move your `Application.cfc` to the root of `site/project89`.

From the ColdFusion docs:

When ColdFusion starts processing the request, it does the following:

> It searches the page's directory for a file named Application.cfc. If
> one exists, it creates a new instance of the CFC, processes the
> initial events, and stops searching. (ColdFusion creates a new
> instance of the CFC and processes its initialization code for each
> request.)
>
> If the requested page's directory does not have an
> Application.cfc file, it checks the directory for an Application.cfm
> file. If one exists, ColdFusion logically includes the Application.cfm
> page at the beginning of the requested page and stops searching
> further. If the requested page's directory does not have an
> Application.cfc or Application.cfm file, ColdFusion searches up the
> directory tree and checks each directory first for an Application.cfc
> file and then, if one is not found, for an Application.cfm page, until
> it reaches the root directory (such as C:).
>
> When it finds an Application.cfc or Application.cfm file, it processes the page and
> stops searching.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appFramework_06.html (ColdFusion 8 but still relevant)

Comment: thank you so much iv been looking for this all day on Friday. And i think I found my problem. I need to use default template for other projects, and I see there is a `application.cfm` file already exist. and it probably conflicts with my cfc file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess under "affected" you mean that it is looking for model CFCs everywhere. If this is true, you can try to solve it by restricting the path of models:

```
this.ormsettings.cfclocation = "path.to.models";
```

Comment: So by declaring `this.ormsettings.cfclocation = "site/project89";` It will not affect other previous projects in "site/project01".. and etc? Because other projects have their own database sources, and I do not want them to crash again. Sorry for such questions, this is my second week playing with CF. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `this.ormsettings.cfclocation` is the location that coldfusion searches for the ORM **models/entities** NOT the `application.cfc` settings, i don't think this is what you are after.